# error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 on CentOS

Tags: python, linux, bash, pip, centos

I'm trying to install lxml package on CentOS using `sudo pip install lxml` and its throwing this error right at the end:

### error:

```
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

---------------------------------------

Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-root/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-PjviBq-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-root/lxml
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log

[hg@user-centos-1 ~]$ error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
bash: error:: command not found
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant portion of `/root/.pip/pip.log` ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Is gcc installed?

```
sudo yum install gcc
```

Comment: `Package gcc-4.4.7-3.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version` is already installed!!!!

Comment: Note that it reads 'command failed', not 'command not found '

Comment: is there any other way to install gcc other than yum as it is not allowed in sagemaker.

Answer (score 64):

" error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 ". the installation failed because of missing python-devel and some dependencies.

the best way to correct gcc problem:

You need to reinstall gcc , gcc-c++ and dependencies.

For python 2.7

```
$ sudo yum -y install gcc gcc-c++ kernel-devel
$ sudo yum -y install python-devel libxslt-devel libffi-devel openssl-devel
$ pip install "your python packet"
```

For python 3.4

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev
$ pip install "your python packet"
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I'm on centos and this worked: `yum install python36-devel`, followed by downloading your package (in my case `python-ldap`)

Comment: On fedora it's dnf install python3-devel

Answer (score 17):

I bet you have to install `libxml2-devel` or `libxml++-devel` or even `python-devel`. But it is only a wild guess, not seeing the actual error from the log file. But it seems `gcc` is missing either a header file or a library file.

Comment: @damiefrancois - I tried installed those and I still get that error!

Comment: Do not try blindly. The error message states: `Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log` so open that file, locate any errors and see exact error messages from `gcc`.

Comment: Installing `python-devel` fixed this for me. Thanks!

Comment: libxml++-devel installing this fixed for me

Comment: Solved installing mysql-devel  (sudo yum install mysql-devel )

Answer (score 15):

```
sudo yum install python36 python36-devel python36-libs python36-tools
```

if using python36, this is the best path for set up. Corrected this error for me on an aws ec2 instance

Comment: I got this error on aws ec2 amazon linux 2[ec2-user@IP ~]$ sudo yum install python36 python36-devel python36-libs python36-tools
Loaded plugins: dkms-build-requires, extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd, versionlock
No package python36 available.
No package python36-devel available.
No package python36-libs available.
No package python36-tools available.
Error: Nothing to do

Answer (score 6):

```
yum install gcc-c++
```

It works for:

- aws ec2 (aws linux)
- [centos](https://www.centos.org/)

  - [8](https://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/CentOS8)
  - [GCP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/os-details)

[Fix “gcc: error trying to exec ‘cc1plus’: execvp: No such file or directory” in Fedora](https://www.unixmen.com/fix-gcc-error-trying-exec-cc1plus-execvp-file-directory-fedora/)

Comment: This is/was the solution for a vanilla Centos 8

Answer (score 4):

How i solved

```
# yum update
# yum install -y https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm
# yum install -y python36u python36u-libs python36u-devel python36u-pip
# pip3.6 install pipenv
```

I hope it will help Someone to resolve "gcc" issue.

Answer (score 4):

```
pip install -U pip
pip install -U cython
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue on `CentOS` while installing `Fasttext`. The issue is fixed with the following.

```
yum install centos-release-scl
yum install scl-utils-build
yum install devtoolset-9
scl enable devtoolset-9 bash
```

Reference: https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/issues/1105#issuecomment-667041482

If the above doesn't work, then try:

```
yum install gcc libffi-devel python-devel openssl-devel -y
```

Reference: https://support.huaweicloud.com/intl/en-us/trouble-ecs/ecs_trouble_0356.html

Answer (score -1):

```
yum install gcc-c++
```

centos GCP , this worked for me |
Installing python3 lib implicit.

Comment: I'm not sure is the previous comment auto-generated, but I think I must reply here. I agree that my answer is already listed in aforementioned posts, but the problem there comes from different environment , different library.. At first, I tried to add an comment there, but I was unabled to do that because I have small reputation score.. Thanks for collaboration.

Comment: I wouldn't add another answer for a different platform. For example, I wouldn't expect there to be three answers for how to install pandas: `pip install pandas` for each of linux, windows, and mac. The other answer already has a comment centos, which has now been edited into that answer.