# Unable to install Kivy on MacOS10.15 using pip

Tags: python, macos, user-interface, kivy, macos-catalina

So I have been using Tkinter up until now to build my GUI's for Python Projects. I want more functionality so - along comes Kivy.

- I am running MacOS10.15.3.
- I have Python 3.8.1 installed, as well as
  Cython 0.29.15.

Following their documentation, [found here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-osx.html#using-conda), I am now on the step

```
pip install kivy
```

However that just outputs the following:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/k9/4_rr59zs7055_wty99dd524w0000gn/T/pip-install-jukuvgg8/kivy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/k9/4_rr59zs7055_wty99dd524w0000gn/T/pip-install-jukuvgg8/kivy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/k9/4_rr59zs7055_wty99dd524w0000gn/T/pip-install-jukuvgg8/kivy/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /private/var/folders/k9/4_rr59zs7055_wty99dd524w0000gn/T/pip-install-jukuvgg8/kivy/
    Complete output (247 lines):
    fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
    Using setuptools
    User distribution detected, avoid portable command.
    Using this graphics system: OpenGL ES 2
    OSX framework used, force to x86_64 only
    OSX ARCHFLAGS are: -arch x86_64
    GStreamer framework not found, fallback on pkg-config
    GStreamer found via pkg-config
    Missing framework /Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework
    Missing framework /Library/Frameworks/SDL2_ttf.framework
    Missing framework /Library/Frameworks/SDL2_image.framework
    Missing framework /Library/Frameworks/SDL2_mixer.framework
    SDL2 frameworks not found, fallback on pkg-config
    SDL2 found via pkg-config
    Xcode detected at b'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer', and using OS X10.15 sdk
    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags pangoft2 (code 1)

    b"Package pangoft2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.\nPerhaps you should add the directory containing `pangoft2.pc'\nto the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable\nNo package 'pangoft2' found\n"

    ERROR: Dependency for context.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for compiler.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for context_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for fbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for gl_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for opengl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for opengl_utils.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for shader.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for stencil_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for scissor_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for texture.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for vbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for vertex.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for vertex_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_mock.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_gl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_glew.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_sdl2.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for svg.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    Compiling /var/folders/k9/4_rr59zs7055_wty99dd524w0000gn/T/easy_install-pto9p2ll/Cython-0.29.10/Cython/Plex/Scanners.py because it changed.
    Compiling /var/folders/k9/4_rr59zs7055_wty99dd524w0000gn/T/easy_install-pto9p2ll/Cython-0.29.10/Cython/Plex/Actions.py because it changed.
    Compiling /var/folders/k9/4_rr59zs7055_wty99dd524w0000gn/T/easy_install-pto9p2ll/Cython-0.29.10/Cython/Compiler/Scanning.py because it changed.
    Compiling /var/folders/k9/4_rr59zs7055_wty99dd524w0000gn/T/easy_install-pto9p2ll/Cython-0.29.10/Cython/Compiler/Visitor.py because it changed.
    Compiling /var/folders/k9/4_rr59zs7055_wty99dd524w0000gn/T/easy_install-pto9p2ll/Cython-0.29.10/Cython/Compiler/FlowControl.py because it changed.
    Compiling /var/folders/k9/4_rr59zs7055_wty99dd524w0000gn/T/easy_install-pto9p2ll/Cython-0.29.10/Cython/Runtime/refnanny.pyx because it changed.
    Compiling /var/folders/k9/4_rr59zs7055_wty99dd524w0000gn/T/easy_install-pto9p2ll/Cython-0.29.10/Cython/Compiler/FusedNode.py because it changed.
    Compiling /var/folders/k9/4_rr59zs7055_wty99dd524w0000gn/T/easy_install-pto9p2ll/Cython-0.29.10/Cython/Tempita/_tempita.py because it changed.
    [1/8] Cythonizing /var/folders/k9/4_rr59zs7055_wty99dd524w0000gn/T/easy_install-pto9p2ll/Cython-0.29.10/Cython/Compiler/FlowControl.py
    [2/8] Cythonizing /var/folders/k9/4_rr59zs7055_wty99dd524w0000gn/T/easy_install-pto9p2ll/Cython-0.29.10/Cython/Compiler/FusedNode.py
    [3/8] Cythonizing /var/folders/k9/4_rr59zs7055_wty99dd524w0000gn/T/easy_install-pto9p2ll/Cython-0.29.10/Cython/Compiler/Scanning.py
    [4/8] Cythonizing /var/folders/k9/4_rr59zs7055_wty99dd524w0000gn/T/easy_install-pto9p2ll/Cython-0.29.10/Cython/Compiler/Visitor.py
    [5/8] Cythonizing /var/folders/k9/4_rr59zs7055_wty99dd524w0000gn/T/easy_install-pto9p2ll/Cython-0.29.10/Cython/Plex/Actions.py
    [6/8] Cythonizing /var/folders/k9/4_rr59zs7055_wty99dd524w0000gn/T/easy_install-pto9p2ll/Cython-0.29.10/Cython/Plex/Scanners.py
    [7/8] Cythonizing /var/folders/k9/4_rr59zs7055_wty99dd524w0000gn/T/easy_install-pto9p2ll/Cython-0.29.10/Cython/Runtime/refnanny.pyx
    [8/8] Cythonizing /var/folders/k9/4_rr59zs7055_wty99dd524w0000gn/T/easy_install-pto9p2ll/Cython-0.29.10/Cython/Tempita/_tempita.py
    /var/folders/k9/4_rr59zs7055_wty99dd524w0000gn/T/easy_install-pto9p2ll/Cython-0.29.10/Cython/Plex/Scanners.c:7241:265: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 15, have 16
      __pyx_codeobj__6 = (PyObject*)__Pyx_PyCode_New(1, 0, 1, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__5, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_var_folders_k9_4_rr59zs7055_wty, __pyx_n_s_read, 113, __pyx_empty_bytes); if (unlikely(!__pyx_codeobj__6)) __PYX_ERR(0, 113, __pyx_L1_error)
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /var/folders/k9/4_rr59zs7055_wty99dd524w0000gn/T/easy_install-pto9p2ll/Cython-0.29.10/Cython/Plex/Scanners.c:333:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
              PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
              ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/code.h:122:12: note: 'PyCode_New' declared here
    PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
               ^
    /var/folders/k9/4_rr59zs7055_wty99dd524w0000gn/T/easy_install-pto9p2ll/Cython-0.29.10/Cython/Plex/Scanners.c:7253:269: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 15, have 16
      __pyx_codeobj__8 = (PyObject*)__Pyx_PyCode_New(1, 0, 1, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__7, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_var_folders_k9_4_rr59zs7055_wty, __pyx_n_s_position, 297, __pyx_empty_bytes); if (unlikely(!__pyx_codeobj__8)) __PYX_ERR(0, 297, __pyx_L1_error)
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /var/folders/k9/4_rr59zs7055_wty99dd524w0000gn/T/easy_install-pto9p2ll/Cython-0.29.10/Cython/Plex/Scanners.c:333:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
              PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
              ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/code.h:122:12: note: 'PyCode_New' declared here
    PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
               ^
    /var/folders/k9/4_rr59zs7055_wty99dd524w0000gn/T/easy_install-pto9p2ll/Cython-0.29.10/Cython/Plex/Scanners.c:7265:274: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 15, have 16
      __pyx_codeobj__10 = (PyObject*)__Pyx_PyCode_New(1, 0, 1, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__9, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_var_folders_k9_4_rr59zs7055_wty, __pyx_n_s_get_position, 308, __pyx_empty_bytes); if (unlikely(!__pyx_codeobj__10)) __PYX_ERR(0, 308, __pyx_L1_error)
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /var/folders/k9/4_rr59zs7055_wty99dd524w0000gn/T/easy_install-pto9p2ll/Cython-0.29.10/Cython/Plex/Scanners.c:333:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
              PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
              ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/code.h:122:12: note: 'PyCode_New' declared here
    PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
               ^
    /var/folders/k9/4_rr59zs7055_wty99dd524w0000gn/T/easy_install-pto9p2ll/Cython-0.29.10/Cython/Plex/Scanners.c:7277:266: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 15, have 16
      __pyx_codeobj__12 = (PyObject*)__Pyx_PyCode_New(1, 0, 1, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__11, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_var_folders_k9_4_rr59zs7055_wty, __pyx_n_s_eof, 334, __pyx_empty_bytes); if (unlikely(!__pyx_codeobj__12)) __PYX_ERR(0, 334, __pyx_L1_error)
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /var/folders/k9/4_rr59zs7055_wty99dd524w0000gn/T/easy_install-pto9p2ll/Cython-0.29.10/Cython/Plex/Scanners.c:333:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
              PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
              ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/code.h:122:12: note: 'PyCode_New' declared here
    PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
               ^
    /var/folders/k9/4_rr59zs7055_wty99dd524w0000gn/T/easy_install-pto9p2ll/Cython-0.29.10/Cython/Plex/Scanners.c:10053:9: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 15, have 16
            __pyx_empty_bytes  /*PyObject *lnotab*/
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /var/folders/k9/4_rr59zs7055_wty99dd524w0000gn/T/easy_install-pto9p2ll/Cython-0.29.10/Cython/Plex/Scanners.c:333:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
              PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
              ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/code.h:122:12: note: 'PyCode_New' declared here
    PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
               ^
    5 errors generated.
     Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.
     warning: no files found matching 'Doc/*'
     warning: no files found matching '*.pyx' under directory 'Cython/Debugger/Tests'
     warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython/Debugger/Tests'
     warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython/Utility'
     warning: no files found matching 'pyximport/README'
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 117, in _compile
         self.spawn(compiler_so + cc_args + [src, '-o', obj] +
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 910, in spawn
         spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run)
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/spawn.py", line 36, in spawn
         _spawn_posix(cmd, search_path, dry_run=dry_run)
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/spawn.py", line 157, in _spawn_posix
         raise DistutilsExecError(
     distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
         dist.run_commands()
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
         self.run_command(cmd)
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
         cmd_obj.run()
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 172, in run
         cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 158, in call_command
         self.run_command(cmdname)
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
         self.distribution.run_command(command)
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
         cmd_obj.run()
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/install_lib.py", line 11, in run
         self.build()
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/install_lib.py", line 107, in build
         self.run_command('build_ext')
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
         self.distribution.run_command(command)
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
         cmd_obj.run()
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 84, in run
         _build_ext.run(self)
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
         self.build_extensions()
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 449, in build_extensions
         self._build_extensions_serial()
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 474, in _build_extensions_serial
         self.build_extension(ext)
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 205, in build_extension
         _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 528, in build_extension
         objects = self.compiler.compile(sources,
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 574, in compile
         self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 120, in _compile
         raise CompileError(msg)
     distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
         yield saved
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
         yield
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
         _execfile(setup_script, ns)
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
         exec(code, globals, locals)
       File "/var/folders/k9/4_rr59zs7055_wty99dd524w0000gn/T/easy_install-pto9p2ll/Cython-0.29.10/setup.py", line 228, in <module>
         This version of Cython is untested with Kivy. While this version may
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 145, in setup
         return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 163, in setup
         raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
     SystemExit: error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1144, in run_setup
         run_setup(setup_script, args)
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 253, in run_setup
         raise
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
         self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
         yield
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
         self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
         saved_exc.resume()
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
         six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/six.py", line 685, in reraise
         raise value.with_traceback(tb)
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
         yield saved
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
         yield
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
         _execfile(setup_script, ns)
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
         exec(code, globals, locals)
       File "/var/folders/k9/4_rr59zs7055_wty99dd524w0000gn/T/easy_install-pto9p2ll/Cython-0.29.10/setup.py", line 228, in <module>
         This version of Cython is untested with Kivy. While this version may
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 145, in setup
         return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 163, in setup
         raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
     SystemExit: error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
       File "/private/var/folders/k9/4_rr59zs7055_wty99dd524w0000gn/T/pip-install-jukuvgg8/kivy/setup.py", line 1073, in <module>
         setup(
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 144, in setup
         _install_setup_requires(attrs)
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 139, in _install_setup_requires
         dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 716, in fetch_build_eggs
         resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 780, in resolve
         dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1065, in best_match
         return self.obtain(req, installer)
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1077, in obtain
         return installer(requirement)
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 786, in fetch_build_egg
         return cmd.easy_install(req)
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 679, in easy_install
         return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 705, in install_item
         dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 890, in install_eggs
         return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1158, in build_and_install
         self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1146, in run_setup
         raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
     distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output
```

Some googling suggests that a) gcc shouldn't be used? and b)maybe it's an issue with SDL2 but  can't quite work it out with either of those.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Potentially useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19955775/error-command-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1-on-centos

Comment: Important part of the error message: _GStreamer framework not found, fallback on pkg-config
    GStreamer found via pkg-config
    Missing framework /Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework
    Missing framework /Library/Frameworks/SDL2_ttf.framework
    Missing framework /Library/Frameworks/SDL2_image.framework
    Missing framework /Library/Frameworks/SDL2_mixer.framework
    SDL2 frameworks not found, fallback on pkg-config
    SDL2 found via pkg-config_

Comment: My (less than ideal) solution would be to give up and use Conda, which is great for these cases which involve many non-python components.

Comment: Hm - I'll install GStreamer, see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Well the error log does contain _GStreamer framework not found, fallback on pkg-config
    GStreamer found via pkg-config_, which seems to indicate GStreamer isn't an issue, no? It very well could be, though, I'm not familiar these libraries.

Comment: Kivy doesn't have packages for Python 3.8 on PyPi, that's why you have problems. Install Python 3.7 or you can try to install master branch by ```pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/```

Comment: @Lothric Looks like that's the issue duh. Will change my version of Python - see if that fixes the issue

Answer (score 6):

You can download latest kivy snapshot wheels here:

https://kivy.org/downloads/ci/osx/kivy/

(cp38 in filename indicates it's meant to be used with Python3.8)

and then just run

```
pip install [path to wheel file]
```

Comment: Thanks, It solved the issue without uninstalling Python 3.8

Answer (score 1):

To fix this - I removed Python 3.8 from my Mac and installed the latest version of Python 3.7 in its place.

I then run the commands listed on Kivy Install instructions for using Homebrew which are:

```
$ brew install pkg-config sdl2 sdl2_image sdl2_ttf sdl2_mixer gstreamer
$ pip install Cython==0.29.10
$ pip install kivy
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $ brew uninstall python@3.8
```

When I follow this instruction on the Kivy download site:

```
    $ brew install pkg-config sdl2 sdl2_image sdl2_ttf sdl2_mixer gstreamer
```

For some reason it reinstalls Python@3.8. So, using homebrew, I uninstalled Python@3.8, uninstalled the sdl2 packages, and uninstalled Cython.

Then I was able to run the code below to get it to work properly:

```
    $ brew install python@3.7
    $ python3 -m pip install Cython --user
    $ python3 -m pip install kivy --user
```

This solved my problem. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Run these 2 commands in terminal:

```
rm -rf $(brew --repo homebrew/core)
brew tap homebrew/core
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).